# Corrupted/Messed up icons on gnome-panel

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel, icons

Sometimes when I start my computer my gnome panel where my notification icons are is sometimes screwed with icons overlapping or not appearing at all. Sometimes my taskbar is also affected where by their is a white gap between the show desktop button and taskbar where open programs appear.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably this [(in)famous bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/439448).

Answer (score 1):

this command kills the process, after that it auto loads the panel again.

```
killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about killing the panels solves the issue, but is there something I can to fix it configuration wise so it doesn't happen at all?